# Is there a way to do a spell check on the static elements of a webpage?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, website, spell-check

for example -  I want to do a spellcheck on a portion of text already there on a webpage, not necessarily in a textbox.

Is it possible through some add-on (Firefox or Chrome) or script?

For example,

> thsi quot has speling erorrs, but you
>   would see them underlined only when you try to
>   edit. Once it is displayed as non
>   editable webpage element, the spell
>   check does not run.

Answer (score 2):

Use following extensions/scripts

- For Google Chrome: [After the Deadline](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fcdjadjbdihbaodagojiomdljhjhjfho?hl=en) [Extension]
- Firefox: [Spell Check](http://lifehacker.com/5335686/use-firefoxs-spell-checker-on-any-page) [Bookmarklet]

Answer (score 0):

Further has an [online spell checker](http://www.further.co.uk/free-website-spellcheck/).